# Scraping counts of articles from WOS using keywords

Tags: r, search, web-scraping, keyword

I have a long list of key words/phrases that I want to search for in Web of Science to get counts of articles (X articles used "term a"). Ideally, the search would look at the titles, abstracts, keywords, and power keywords (this is what Web of Science searches). Ideally I could also specify specific years to search, although that's not imperative. I am trying to find a way to do that using R OR Python instead of having to keep changing the entries and clicking back and forth. Even if it pulled a list of the unique article titles for each keyword or keyword combination, I could then do the count myself. Is there a way to do this?

For example:
I want to search for the # of articles posted based on different search terms: 
"term a"
"term b"
"term c"
"term d"

Then I want to run a search for the # of articles posted that have pairs of terms:
"term a" and "term b"
"term a" and "term c"
"term a" and "term d"

Finally, I want to run searches for the # of articles posted that have larger groups of terms:
"term a" and "term b" and "term c" OR
"term a" and "term b" and "term d"

I hope that makes sense. No clue if this exists- but haven't been able to find it yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Python is not R

Comment: Sorry I meant to say in my post that I am open to using Python OR R

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754051/how-to-retrieve-informations-about-journals-from-isi-web-of-knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `R` (specifically the `RSelenium` package) as a hacky way to get at scraping citation counts. You can format a character vector in R that looks similar to "TS=(term a AND term B)" for a single entry, and then query WOS using advanced search. You'll have to edit 
[this gist](https://gist.github.com/taddallas/cbf0589df1fa9051d774b2d282b6e635) to get what you'd like to get out of it, but it could serve as a nice starting point.